# Remove all numbers in brackets with the brackets from string

Tags: java, regex

Trying to remove city code from string for my additional 
I have wrote the brackets removal with indexOf. how to do this with regex?

Mr Smith  (344) 455 66 44

to

Mr Smith 455 66 44

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("\\(\\d+\\)", "");`

Comment: Please note, that regular expressions are basically only a way of *finding* strings - the replacement is only using regex to replace the result of the regex match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
String clean = str.replaceAll("\\(\\d+\\)", "");
```